# Display Predicted Segmentation Output Data in Pyplot

Tags: python, numpy, mnist, imshow

I'm attempting to plot an array of output data from a U-net. The array contains mnist data that has been one-hot encoded for image segmentation.

it's shape is:
(28,28,11)

So, for each place in the original image where the pixel value is 0, the one-hot encoding would place an array of [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1], indicating that this pixel is blank.

If on the other hand the pixel value is > 0, the one-hot array would show the classification of the overall image.

EX: If the mnist image is of a 2, each pixel where the value is > 0 would be turned into an array [0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0].

I'm wondering if there's a way to display such an array, with each element of the array being made up of a one-hot array.

I've tried to just use plt.imshow on the data, however, it throws an error saying that the "TypeError: Invalid dimensions for image data"

Here is the code I'm working with

```
from keras import applications
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras import optimizers
import skimage.transform
import cv2
import sys
from keras import Input
from keras import backend as K
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.models import Sequential, Model 
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.losses import categorical_crossentropy
from keras.optimizers import adam
from keras.layers import Conv2D, Dense, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dropout, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras.datasets import cifar10
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.utils import np_utils
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

y_train = y_train[:10]

data = np.random.choice(255, (10,128,128))


## do you calculation of brightness here
## and expand it to one row per pixel
arr = data.reshape(-1,1)/255
## repeat labels to match the expanded pixel
labels = y_train.repeat(128*128).reshape(-1,1)

ind_row = np.arange(len(arr))
ind_col = np.where(arr>0, labels, 10).ravel()

one_hot_coded_arr = np.zeros((len(arr), 11))
one_hot_coded_arr[ind_row,ind_col]=1

## convert back to desired shape
one_hot_coded_arr = one_hot_coded_arr.reshape(-1, 128,128,11)
#print(one_hot_coded_arr[:28,:])
print(one_hot_coded_arr.shape)


plt.imshow(one_hot_coded_arr, interpolation='nearest')
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

I want to display an image something like this:
https://documentation.sas.com/api/docsets/casdlpg/8.4/content/images/mnistout2.png

But I keep running into the error 
"TypeError: Invalid dimensions for image data"

Any help would be amazing, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have too many dimensions. `matplotlib.pyplot` only plots 2 dimensions (x, y).

Therefore, you should first choose your image to display i.e. `output[n]`. Next, as it's one hot encoded, use the `np.argmax(output[n], axis=-1)` function to 'unencode'.

Alternatively, just select the layer you want `output[n,:,:,l]`.

Let me know if that works.